# Append information to Excel file on GridView Export in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, export-to-excel

I'm exporting a GridView to Excel with the following code:

```
protected void export_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
    // Let's hide all unwanted stuffing
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.AllowSorting = false;

    // Let's bind data to GridView
    BindGrid();

    //Change the color back to white
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#ffffff");


    //Apply color to the header
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#e0e0e0");
    }

    // Let's output the Gridview
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + reportid + ".xls");

    StringWriter swriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(swriter);

    GridView1.RenderControl(hwriter);

    Response.Write(style);
    Response.Write(swriter.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
```

Now I need to append a Name on the first row, Date & Time on the second row and possibly some other information on the third row. I will also like to leave a row between the actually GridView data and this information. Is this possible? If so, would you be so kind and provide some examples on how can I accomplish this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go ahead and add it. Add a carriage return after each to make Excel advance to the next row (use tabs to advance to the next cell).

```
Response.Write(style);
Response.Write("Pretty Excel Export File\n");
Response.Write("Generated on " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "\n\n");
Response.Write(swriter.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: I'm sorry what should I use for tab?

Comment: Neither \r or \t are working. When I use \r it doesn't more to the next row and when I use \t it doesn't move to the next cell

Comment: Actually it's \n for a newline. I thought I remembered combining this with an HTML export, but I might be mistaken. Try wrapping your prefixed data in an HTML Table.